# How to make the scrollviewer work in this scenario?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, scrollviewer

Having some problems with my MVVM Application.
So the scenario is the following:

- In my MainWindow.xaml, I have a ContentControl placed in a Grid Column, its content is bind to the CurrentViewModel which will be rendered to the appropriate View (in this case, Overview.xaml).

  ```
          <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
  ```
- Within this particular view (Overview.xaml) there are multiple UserControls placed within a StackPanel.

  ```
  <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
  <StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="True">
      <views:DiagramView DataContext="{Binding Path=DiagramViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:IncomeCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=IncomesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:ExpenseCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=ExpensesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:CheckCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=ChecksViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:BalanceCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=BalancesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:VacationCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=VacationsViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:KHCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=KhViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
      <views:OctaviaCollectionView DataContext="{Binding Path=OctaviaViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
  </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
  ```
- Each UserControl within this StackPanel has a very similar look (obviously there are more stuff in the XAML). **There is no constant value regarding Width or Height within my application**.

  ```
          <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedCollection}}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}">
          <ListView.GroupStyle>
              <GroupStyle>
                  <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].CurrentCategory}" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
              </GroupStyle>
          </ListView.GroupStyle>
          <ListView.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <UniformGrid Columns="12" Rows="1" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemsPanel>
          <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style>
                  <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GeneratedColumn}"/>
              </Style>
          </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding EncryptedAmount}" />
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <TextBlock Text="Got paid on " />
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <Button Content="details"
                              Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowDialogCommand,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                              CommandParameter="QuickEdit"/>
                      <Button Content="remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Income removed." />
                  </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
  ```

**The problem is that I can't seem to make the vertical scrollviewer work.** It is displayed because I make it visible, but it's disabled. Obviously the StackPanel is gonna grow indefintely, but isn't there a way for it to calculate how much space is needed? Because most of the content is just cut off right now.
So I tried to put scrollviewer in every possible place, but they're all disabled.

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <ContentPresenter Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So then I tried dropping the StackPanel implementation and tried it with a Grid.
Nope, it doesn't work either.
Obviously I'm missing some basis solution here, but just can't figure it out.
Any ideas would be appreciated, seems like a very common scenario to be honest.
Cheers

```
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <views:DiagramView DataContext="{Binding Path=DiagramViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
        <views:IncomeCollectionView Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=IncomesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
        <views:ExpenseCollectionView Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding Path=ExpensesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
        <views:CheckCollectionView Grid.Row="3" DataContext="{Binding Path=ChecksViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" /> 
           ...etc...
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Edit: The DiagramView UserControl contains the following:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Expense.Manager.WPF.Views.DiagramView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:pie="clr-namespace:Expense.Manager.WPF.CustomPie"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Expense.Manager.WPF.Shared"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="BoolToBrushConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Income this month: " />
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="Retrieving data...">
                        <Binding Path="EncryptedCurrentMonthIncome" Mode="TwoWay" IsAsync="True" />
                    </PriorityBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <pie:PieChart Data="{Binding PieChartIncomeData, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="250" PieWidth="130" PieHeight="130" Height="140" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Expenses this month: " />
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="Retrieving data...">
                        <Binding Path="CurrentMonthExpense" Mode="TwoWay" IsAsync="True" />
                    </PriorityBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <pie:PieChart Data="{Binding PieChartExpenseData, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="250" PieWidth="130" PieHeight="130" Height="140" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding VacationsLeft}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" days left" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VacationsPerYearCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" Height="25" Width="4" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToBrushConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Bank savings:" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BankSavings}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

IncomeCollectionView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Expense.Manager.WPF.Views.IncomeCollectionView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Expense.Manager.WPF.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="groupedCollection" IsLiveGroupingRequested="True" Source="{Binding Collection}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CurrentCategory" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="SemiBold" Padding="5" Background="SteelBlue" />
            <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedCollection}}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}">
                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].CurrentCategory}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Columns="12" Rows="1" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding GeneratedColumn}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EncryptedAmount}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Date}" />
                            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="details"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowDialogCommand,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                CommandParameter="QuickEdit"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Income removed." />

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

and where it is used:
why is the listview not resizing itself after resizing the window itself?

```
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <views:IncomeCollectionView Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=IncomesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I tried dropping the `StackPanel` implementation and tried it with a `Grid`. Nope, it doesn't work either.*

That's almost correct, apart from the last sentence. Using a `Grid` is half of the answer, because the `StackPanel` has no functionality to resize its items... you just need to inform the `ScrollViewer` when to scroll. Take this example:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Cyan" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Fill="Orange" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Fill="Purple" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" Fill="Yellow" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This XAML will make the `ScrollViewer ScrollBar` appear (once the `Window.Height` is small enough), but if you remove the `RowDefinition.Height` values (thereby giving each row a proportion of the whole `Grid.Height`), you'll see your previous situation where no `ScrollBar` appears.

Now, none of us want to hard code constant values into our UIs, but you can do this using the `Auto` setting on the `RowDefinition.Height` properties instead. Unlike these `Rectangle`s, your controls will all have some `Height`, so your solution is to set each of your `Grid.RowDefinition`s like this:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
```

This will provide your controls with as much space as they need within the `Grid` and therefore (hopefully) they will have more `Height` together than the `ScrollViewer` and therefore the `ScrollViewer` will display its vertical `ScrollBar`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work unfortunately as shown below: dropbox.com/s/b6e5uj1coxtvi0t/grid.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Doesn't even work with 1 UserControl. Horizontal scrollbar works fine but the vertical is disabled at all times.`<Grid> <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <views:DiagramView DataContext="{Binding Path=DiagramViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
        </Grid>`

Comment: Hey, let's be clear... perhaps *your code* doesn't work, but *this code* works just fine. If you didn't before, try it now... you'll see that it *does* work. I've explained how to solve your problem. The `ScrollViewer` content simply needs to report a bigger total `Height` than the `ScrollViewer.Height`.

Comment: That's why I added the source code to DiagramView.xaml, I have a grid defined with 1 row, its Height is set to Auto and it's wrapped around with a ScrollViewer. This row contains the Diagram View. But no matter how I resize the Window, the scrollbar is disabled.

Comment: You're not listening. Your `ScrollViewer` content *must report some `Height`*... try setting some `MinHieght` properties on its content objects if you don't want to set exact `Height` values.

Comment: I added minheight to every grid, usercontrol etc., i replaced every stackpanel with grid, deleted, all i have now is a grid with a listview in it. i set the maxheight to 180, but the horizontal scrollbar is still disabled, and the content within the usercontrol is not resized, no matter what i do, that's the problem, the whole usercontrol is is the same size no matter what the size of the window is. i thought replaced stackpanel with a grid will solve that since the grid resizes its elements but it doesn't do anything for me. this is so frustrating now.

Comment: You still haven't constrained the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer`. I can't say it any simpler... in order for the `ScrollViewer` to be able to scroll its contents, *the contents must have a larger combined `Height` than the `ScrollViewer.Height`*. If you don't set any `Height` (either directly, or indirectly via a `RowDefinition` or a `MaxHeight` value), then it simply won't work.